# How to parse unpredictable JSON objects?

Tags: java, android, json

My app parse JSON from an API based on user's selection. Since each user's search might be different I can't predict what the user will search and have a established parsing structure waiting for them every time I finish a API call.

The problem is how can I have a JSON parsing structure in my app that will handle this undefined/unpredictable JSON object from the different API call?

Basically what I need is a way to handle unpredictable and unknown JSON object like they were known and I could parse their keys and the data inside them.

Thank you.

Comment: Um, use a JSON parser. Most common JSON parsers for Android support parsing to generic structures (e.g., `Map<String, Object>`) or offer a bespoke API for navigating the structure (e.g., `JSONObject`).

Comment: Would you mind giving me a practical example for my case?

Comment: Well, there is [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), and there is [`JsonReader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html), to name the two that are part of the Android SDK. Both of them work with arbitrary JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper to convert your JSON to some key-value structure object like Map or HashMap:

`Map<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonData, Map.class);`

`jsonData` can be file, stream, byte, string,....

More detail here: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(byte[],%20java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 0):

I would help more if I had your Code but hope my explanation will work for you. I recently made an app that picks stuff entered by users on the server-side and display on phone. For instance you choose rice and fish while another person chooses rice, fish, coffee and baked beans. These are different stuff but I made an array to hold the stuff, the length of the array depends on the number of stuff you pick. then I build a json object to parse. Note: you can count the number of items the user put and safe in the variable then use that variable as the length.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getString(KEY_SUCCESS).equals("true")) {
              JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                   JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

I had saved all user input with "data". One thing my answer may not fit your description because I am not sure if you are getting a list input from user or something like a long paragraph/article. I assumed you are getting a list so I gave you an option to use arrays

Comment: My JSON response is a nested JSON Object (multiple json objects inside another json object) for that reason I can't parse as it was jsonArra.

Do you have any other idea to help?